# AWS Lightsail - Static IP not visible in ifconfig

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have created AWS Lightsail instance and attached a public IP address. So Curranty machine has 2 IPs, public and private.

the command ifconfig shows only private IP and nowhere in public. Hence I am unable to bind my golang based application to public IP address.

Am I missing anything here? I have spend 1 hour on chasing this and could not see any article that could relate to this, need help.

Answer (score 4):

AWS provides static IPs via NAT. The static IP is part of the AWS network, and traffic to that IP will be routed to the private IP of your instance within the AWS network.

Comment: Hi @Mark 
Looks interesting.... the architecture for public ip (or elastic ip as well). I would love love to know how traffic goes into vms deployed in public subnets using public/elastic ip. Already tried to googling, but couldn't found useful blogs. Please help if there is any blog.

Comment: I have a similar issue, on my Lightsail machine I have two public IPs: an IPv4 one and an IPv6 one. I want to use the IPv6 to reach my machine without configuring any DNS (IPv6 because for some reason IPv4 changes when I reboot the machine). Everything was working fine through Postman (e.g. wget http://\[xxxx:xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx\]:3000/sample_image.png), my backend is still running as a service, I can reach it through the new IPv4 but now the IPv6 anymore. Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH xxxx:xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:3000 - Local (:::49702).
Any ideas why ?